# Do I need to use "Marking extra actions for routing" in this REST Django API?

Tags: django, api, rest, django-urls

I'm currently having this issue. I have to set up an URL like this:

```
.../users/<user_id>/user_action/
```

There are many **users** and when I pick **one user** (with user_id), I will be able to see the user's information. Then, go to /user_action, I will be able to POST actions for that specific user.

In this case, do I have to use the [Marking extra actions for routing](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) or do I just need to make a separate Viewset for user_action (then link it to users/<user_id>/ in the urls.py)?